# Where can I find out-of-print Catan geographies?

Tags: catan

Anyone have any ideas? I see a bunch on the Catan shop, but only a select few are actually for sale. http://www.catan.com/board-games/settlers-catan/variants-and-scenarios/regional-editions

I've tried ebay, I've tried Amazon, a bunch of sites...  Any suggestions on where I would find a used "[Austria](http://www.catan.com/game/catan-geographies-austria)" Catan Map (*English* edition), and the like?

Comment: http://boardgamegeek.com/ would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Mayfair (English) version is out of print, you'll have to rely on communities like boardgamegeek. Today, they have [just one English version](http://boardgamegeek.com/geekmarket/product/629275) (new condition) but it only ships to the US.

The German version is on stock at [Catanshop.de](http://www.catanshop.de/spiele-und-erweiterungen/die-siedler-von-osterreich.html).